# Webservice API Nomadesk

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, api, child-nodes

I am trying to use the Nomadesk API for my website to allow users to upload images to my vault so that I can show them on a specific page on my website.

To be able to upload images with the Nomadesk API I need to use 2 things:

1.https://secure.nomadesk.com/ctrller/api.php?Task=Logon&Email=api@nomadesk.com&Password=password
This wil respond with a token in XMl if you are using the correct e-mail and password.

2.https://secure.nomadesk.com/ctrller/api.php?Token=rrc1d3ntb53tt6b2vhail6rdtrsxov3v&Task=GetFileservers&ShowUserList=true
Here I will get all the vault that are available for my account.

Now for my question:

The first link will give me a XML response with in it a childnode named: Token.
I need to save the Token and use it in the second link (As shown above).

How do I save a childnode in like a session or a list so that it will automatically use it in the second link without actually typing it in a different class?

```
    public string VaultSession { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Token")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }


    public void XMLNomadesk()
    {
        List<NomadeskVault> XmlToken = new List<NomadeskVault>();
        try
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("https://secure.nomadesk.com/ctrller/api.php?" + Task + "/Logon/" + Email + "/Content@JHarry.com/" + Password + "/TestTestTest/");
            XmlElement rootElement = doc.DocumentElement;

            string Url = null;

            foreach (XmlNode child in rootElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                /*if (child.Name.ToLower() == "token")
                {
                    string token = child.InnerText;
                }*/
                if (child.Name == "Message")
                    Message = child.InnerText;

                if (child.Name == "Token")
                    Token = child.InnerText;

            }

            if (Url != "")
                XmlToken.Add(new NomadeskVault(Url, Token, Task, Email, Password));


        }

        catch
        {

        }
    }


 public static NomadeskVault Current
    {
        get
        {
            NomadeskVault session =
                (NomadeskVault)HttpContext.Current.Session["VaultSession"];
            if (session == null)
            {
                session = new NomadeskVault();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["VaultSession"] = session;
            }
            return session;
        }
    }
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

The structure might be all wrong because I just started programming in C#.

Thanks!
Cheers!!

Comment: Can you share the XML response of your first call ? Your code will not work if Token node is not a direct child of the root element.

Comment: <Response>
    <Status>1</Status>
    <Message></Message>
    <Token>realorgc0vl7jtipak1qra1nc3</Token>
    <AccountInfo>
        <FirstName>api</FirstName>
        <LastName>003</LastName>
        <Email>api@nomadesk.com</Email>
        <Language>en-us</Language>
        <BrandingID>NMD</BrandingID>
        <IsTrial>true</IsTrial>
    </AccountInfo>
</Response>

Comment: The only thing I need for the second call is the token

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because it only reads the first node : `Response`. You have to read all the hierarchy.

Simply do the following, which will search for all the `Token` elements:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("yoururl.com");
XmlNodeList elements = document.GetElementsByTagName("Token");
if (elements.Count == 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Token not found");
}
else
{
    Token = elements[0].InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Aha, thank you sir! So the token will now save in the list or in the session?

Comment: In the property defined in your code: `public string Token { get; set; }`